# Intel i915 and xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property

Tags: intel-graphics, backlight, i915, screen-energy-saving

When I run `xbacklight` I get

```
xbacklight 
No outputs have backlight property
```

I've seen other posts mentions this but I do have a `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`. I can write to the file and this works perfectly fine

```
echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness # (dim)
echo 4000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness # (bright)
```

I'm using the Intel i915 video driver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem was fixed by updating my microcode.

> https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode#Updating_CPU_microcode_within_Debian_.28Intel_or_AMD.29

This did /something/ to my i915, and now it just works.